# What are the ways of ensuring pattern with partial match without using uniqueness?

Tags: neo4j

It's a commonly known pitfall that `MERGE` creates either all nodes or none of them when you give it a complex pattern. If you don't have uniqueness constraints, then `MERGE` will create duplicate nodes, by design.

I was wondering if there is a way to ensure a pattern exists, while utilizing matches.

e.g. for this pattern:

```
(Person {name: "Bob"})-[:FRIEND_OF]->(Person {name: "Alice"})-[:FRIEND_OF]->(Person {name: "Chloe"})
```

The database could be in various states:

1. Bob and Chloe exist but Alice doesn't. Alice should be created.
2. All 3 exist but none of them are friends, relation should be created.
3. Alice and Chloe exist and are friends, Bob should be created.

and so on.

In the end result, I want that the pattern is somehow ensured. I understand that the `MERGE` operation perhaps wasn't built to ensure this. Is there a specific way of dealing with this issue, or am I supposed to just ensure this at application level, and in problem/domain-specific ways to ensure efficiency?

Comment: If you first merge each node separately and then each relationship it should work as intended. Using unique constraint will speed up the import as it also creates an index

Comment: @TomažBratanič unfortunately that does not work. e.g. there might be another "Alice" who's friends with other people. I don't want to merge a friendship between that Alice and Bob, but I want a new Alice to be created if Bob exists. I think I should update the example as this is a bit unnatural.

Comment: Then you always create a new node. how do you know if it os existing Alice or new Alice?

Comment: Ah. Actually I guess the requirements aren't well-specified here. I think I'll close the question and think harder about it.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha This question has not been closed yet.